# marionette compositeview itemview with rows

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

Hi could anyone explain a good solution to produce the following markup using marionette

```
<div class="row">
 <p>itemview 1</p>
 <p>itemview 2</p>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <p>itemview 3</p>
 <p>itemview 4</p>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <p>itemview 5</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CollectionView ->
  itemView : ItemView

ItemView ->
  className : 'row'
  template :
     <p>itemview 3</p>
     <p>itemview 4</p>
```

**Edit**

Ohh, seems like I understood what you want:
https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md#collectionviews-appendhtml

And inside this method you can create a row and insert items you want to it.

Comment: Can you elaborate maybe with a code example. I think I need to do some magic at some point based on the itemview index but not sure exactly where.